# Why partition.size turn to zero in foreachPartition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In the following code(written in scala), I print partition.size twice but got two different results.

Code:

```
val a = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(a)

 rdd.foreachPartition {
      partition =>
      println("1. partition.size: " + partition.size) //1. partition.size: 2
      println("2. partition.size: " + partition.size) //2. partition.size: 0
 }
```

Results:

```
1. partition.size: 2
2. partition.size: 0
```

According to the Spark API doc, partition is a type of Iterator

```
  def foreachPartition(f: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Unit): Unit
      Applies a function f to each partition of this RDD.
```

So why the size of partition is set to 0 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After digging i found the answer, Its not an issue with either the Spark or your program. It basically works as designed. I mean the foreachpartition method closure takes the Iterator[T] as a input which is a scala iterator. When size() method is invoked on the scala iterator, it computes the size and moves to the end of the list. look at the documentation from Scala Iterator,

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_43.html

> The number of elements returned by it. **Note: it will be at its end after this operation!**

When you ask Iterator to give you the size it will traverse each element in the sequence it points to, moving each time one position to the right. When it has no more elements to traverse iterator.hasNext == false it will return the size. But by then it will have exhausted all the elements. **And hence when the size is retrieved for the second time it returns 0**

Comment: @Moriarty, Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And the documentation of Scala Iterator is quite helpful too. Since it is right to return 0 after an iteration, I found another interesting thing that **Array[T].iterator.size** returns a non-zero value every time it is called. I will read the source code of **scala.Array** and find the answer later. Thank you again. :)